# Building new fields from concatenated string

Tags: python, string, dataframe, delimiter

one of my fields in my dataframe includes concatenated string with ; delimiter e.g:

D=1,1;BL1=2,14;BL2=2,14;1=0,4;2=0,1;3=0,1;4=0,4;A=1,14;B=1,14;C=1,1

i tried using string functions like str.find('BL1') to find the new fields but don't know how to build  the new fields and values recursively

i want to create new fields from the string so that my fields will be

```
new field 1: D   value: 1
new field 2: BL1 value: 2,14
new field 3: 1   value: 0
etc....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> st = "D=1,1;BL1=2,14;BL2=2,14;1=0,4;2=0,1;3=0,1;4=0,4;A=1,14;B=1,14;C=1,1"
>>> fragments = [s.split('=') for s in st.split(';')]
>>> d = { f[0]: f[1] for f in fragments }

>>> print(d)
{'A': '1,14', 'C': '1,1', 'B': '1,14', 'D': '1,1', 'BL1': '2,14', 'BL2': '2,14', '1': '0,4', '3': '0,1', '2': '0,1', '4': '0,4'}

>>> print(d['BL1'])
2,14

>>> print(d['1'])
0,4
```

Comment: thanks a lot! 
i need a code that will work in a series because the string is a field in a dataframe with a lot of rows.